# Why i Can't write to mdf file?

Tags: sql-server

I created mdf file that contain tables ( sql express 2008 )
Now, after couple of weeks that i did not touched this file - i trying to create some new table ( the file is not under source control and its not read only ) i get error message that i cant save the table because the file is read only.

I try to open the file thru the SQL Server 2008 application - but with not success. 
When i try to 'get' table using visual studio 2010 connection - i can see the table ( but cant add some new item row )

What to do ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I said in the question that the read only flag is turn off. i try to restart the service , try to rebot the machine .. nothing help

Comment: What error message do you get? This is probably a permissions problem. Either file ACL permissions read-only flag, or database permissions (since an MDF file is a full-featured SQL Server database in a file, it has all the SQL Server security features).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the read-only attribute for the file, there is also the Permissions in the Security tab of the file's Property dialog. Does your current username have Modify permissions? Or are you a windows Admin?

Comment: Or the user account that the database engine is running as - probably NETWORK_SERVICE

Answer (score 1):

What if you try

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDB SET  READ_WRITE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Comment: I can't do anything by using the 'SQL Server Management Studio' so using some other sql call does not work also.

Comment: Why can't you use SSMS? In any event you could use osql or just write some code to do it.

Comment: I can use SSMS - but the SSMS is not able to do action ( like add table ) on the file.